# Icinga2 cluster node local checks not executing

Tags: linux, nagios, network-monitoring

I am using Icinga2-2.3.2 cluster HA setup with three nodes in the same zone and database in a seperate server for idodb. All are Cent OS 6.5. Installed IcingaWeb2 in the active master.

Configured four local checks for each node including cluster health check as described in the documentation. Installed Icinga Classi UI in all three nodes, beacuse I am not able to see the local checks configured for nodes in Icinga Web2.

Configs are syncing, checks are executing & all three nodes are connected among them. But the configured local checks, specific to the node alone are not happening properly and verified it in the classic ui.
        a. All local checks are executed only one time whenever
            - one of the node is disconnected or reconnected
            - configuration changes done in the master and reload icinga2
        b. But after that, only one check is hapenning properly in one node and the remaining are not.

I have attached the screenshot of all node classic ui. 
[image: Node1 Classi UI(Active master)][image: Node2 Classi UI][image: Node3 Classic UI]
Please help me to fix and Thanks in advance.